# Is Raphael an alternative to Flash based web app

Tags: flash, web-applications, html5-canvas, raphael

I am developing a web app which requires rotating and scaling one Image over the other. Image to be rotated and scaled should have a transparent background.

For this I tried using KinecticJS which uses HTML5 canvas element but because of Canvas element's image rendering techniques, my Image was getting distorted.

Now, I have option of moving either to RaphaelJS or to Flash but I am not getting sure-shot idea which to choose.

Can anyone please suggest the pros and cons when RaphaelJS is compared to Flash.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: In some browsers, if you load the image from an svg, it will actually render post-transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for your help.
I found my solution using PaperJS. It specifically provides functions to handle Raster Images.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from your app.

If you are using `JS` in your app then go with `Raphael JS`. It is very easy to create interactive app with `Raphael JS`. 
 Although, Raphael is a little heavy to use in the webapp, but you should also cosider the fact that flash is very heavy too. You should compare the timing on different browsers using flash and Raphael JS.

Depending how big is your flash or how many `Raphael elements` your using on your webapp, the loading time will differ.

Answer (score 0):

If those are your only two requirements for the image manipulation I would completely recommend using Raphael.

The main pros of Raphael for this project are that:

- It will be lighter than a FLASH.
- Raphael is supported across platforms and devices, whereas Flash is not (this is one of the major drawback of Flash).

The cons of using Raphael would be that:

- It has less support for more complex image manipulation and animation. For example, if you need to group several images together and apply transformation to them, this is harder to accomplish with Raphael. FLASH, on the other hand, makes it very easy to group images together and apply transformations to them.

In your description you mention that you need to manipulate just "one image" so the cons won't be a major setback for your particular project.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've started building a prototype in RaphaelJS but I'm facing a problem. I've loaded an Image in PNG format with transparent background and it is displayed just fine. But when I rotate the image, its edges start to blur. Can you suggest how should I tackle this ?

Comment: I tried checking this and I don't get the same error, so I think this might be linked to your image and not to Raphael. Do you encounter this problem with every single image you load?

Comment: Yes I was having same problem with every single image i loaded.